# How to load more data in NVD3's lineWithFocusChart when the viewfinder boundary intersects the right or left margin in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Looking at the code, I haven't quite figured out yet how NVD3's [lineWithFocusChart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html) creates the focus window but I believe it does so by making two rectangles on the sides.  My question is, is how could one make it so it triggers some event when one of the focus windows boundaries hits the side of the viewfinder - ie. so you could load more data?
For example, at the moment, I have it loading a month's worth of data and would like it to load another month when the viewfinder hits left margin.

I'm attempting to trigger an event in the nv.d3.js source code in the onBrush() function:

```
function onBrush() {
    brushExtent = brush.empty() ? null : brush.extent();
    var extent = brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent();
    //The brush extent cannot be less than one.  If it is, don't update the line chart.
    if (Math.abs(extent[0] - extent[1]) <= 1) {
      return;
    }
    if (extent[1] !== x2.domain()[1] && extent[0] === x2.domain()[0]) //my attempt    
        console.log("Wheaton!");  // my attempt - do something here
    dispatch.brush({extent: extent, brush: brush});


    updateBrushBG();

    // Update Main (Focus)
    var focusLinesWrap = g.select('.nv-focus .nv-linesWrap')
        .datum(
          data
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.disabled })
            .map(function(d,i) {
              return {
                key: d.key,
                values: d.values.filter(function(d,i) {
                  return lines.x()(d,i) >= extent[0] && lines.x()(d,i) <= extent[1];
                })
              }
            })
        );
```

So, now the question becomes, if it is done this way, and maybe this isn't the right way to do it, how do I notify the other program that this event has occurred so it can load more data?

Comment: It sounds like you would simply need to call the function to get more data when the condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question:)
This is what worked for me, whether or not, it is the best way I don't know (probably not).  I would welcome a better solution if someone's got one.

Outside of NVD3 I created a function on rootScope to broadcast an event that other functions can listen for, and I pass $rootScope to NVD3 and call the broadcaster inside of onBrush().

Eg.

In my directive that encapsulates NVD3:

```
    ...
    $rootScope.loadMoreData = function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loadMoreData');
    }
    ...
    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart($rootScope); // which gets passed to NVD3
    ...
```

In nv.d3 source code:

```
...
nv.models.lineWithFocusChart = function(rootScope) { // add parameter
...
   function onBrush() {
        brushExtent = brush.empty() ? null : brush.extent();
        var extent = brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent();
        //The brush extent cannot be less than one.  If it is, don't update the line chart.
        if (Math.abs(extent[0] - extent[1]) <= 1) {
          return;
        }
        if (extent[1] !== x2.domain()[1] && extent[0] === x2.domain()[0])   
           rootScope.loadMoreData();
        dispatch.brush({extent: extent, brush: brush});


        updateBrushBG();

        // Update Main (Focus)
        var focusLinesWrap = g.select('.nv-focus .nv-linesWrap')
            .datum(
              data
                .filter(function(d) { return !d.disabled })
                .map(function(d,i) {
                  return {
                    key: d.key,
                    values: d.values.filter(function(d,i) {
                      return lines.x()(d,i) >= extent[0] && lines.x()(d,i) <= extent[1];
                    })
                  }
                })
            );
        focusLinesWrap.transition().duration(transitionDuration).call(lines);


        // Update Main (Focus) Axes
        g.select('.nv-focus .nv-x.nv-axis').transition().duration(transitionDuration)
            .call(xAxis);
        g.select('.nv-focus .nv-y.nv-axis').transition().duration(transitionDuration)
            .call(yAxis);
      }


}
```

And in the controller:
...

```
$rootScope.$on('loadMoreData', function() {

    // reload the data with new date range 
    $scope.data = foo.query();
});
```

Maybe a knucklehead way to do it, I don't feel comfortable mucking around in nv.d3's source code or using $rootScope but it's working till I figure out a better way.